# How to get dailymotion trending?

Tags: php, api, curl, dailymotion-api

I am using below url to get Dailymotion trending videos, If i open the url in browser, it gives the correct data, but while scrapping the api using php, it gives me different results..

https://api.dailymotion.com/videos?fields=title&flags=no_live,no_premium&private=0&sort=trending&limit=20&country=in

Comment: I get same result in browser and in php

Comment: @fusion3k The result differ for me too as MK MK said.

Comment: For me totally identical. For you different in why? number of records, structure or fields content? Could be a country ‘issue’?

Comment: Structure is same, but the records(title) are different. I also suspect there is some country issue, but unable to sort it now :/

Comment: You'd better show sample of what results do you get via PHP API, as it seems not everyone can see the difference

Answer (score 0):

With provided URL, it seems that DailyMotion API ignore the `country` parameter.

Fast reading API DOC, I understand that `country` parameter is used to set locale or as returned value.

To obtain language-filtered results, you can use `language`:

> https://api.dailymotion.com/videos?fields=title&flags=no_live,no_premium&private=0&sort=trending&limit=20&language=in

This works for me.